# Show that given a convex quadrilateral Q of area 1, there is a rectangle R of area 2 such that Q can be drawn inside R

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry, polygons

The question is:

Show that given a convex quadrilateral Q of area 1, there is a rectangle
R of area 2 such that Q can be drawn inside R.

How do you even approach a problem like this?

I was only able to do this by taking Q to be a square and a rectangle, it is then easy to find 2 sides of a rectangle with area 2 such that the given statement true depending on the sides of the original rectangle..

Also, I saw that Q need not be a rectangle, it can be any convex polygon..how do we prove it then? Can anyone please provide the complete formal proof of the above statements?

PS:I wasn't able to find any relevant answers on Approach0 or while reviewing this question..I am looking for a neat way to approach such problems..

Thanks for any answers!!

Comment: Can anyone please give me the entire proof?..I have got the intuition now..but I wanna know how such problems are dealt with more formally..

Comment: (following up on comment on deleted solution) IIRC the casework for non-acute quad is 1) 2 opposite obtuse angles and 2) 2 adjacent obtuse angles. The approach is very similar, but you just need to painfully chase the details down

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Consider the longest edge/diagonal of the polygon. Consider perpendiculars from those vertices.

---

Note: This is true for any convex polygon, not just quadrilaterals.

If you want the answer...

> [From Cut The Knot](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/Generalization/PolygonInRectangle.shtml#proof)

Comment: The answer there is not entirely clear..at the end the author just says this method can be enlarged to any convex polygon.....

Comment: "It follows that the area of R is at most 2. If need be, to answer the requirement it may be enlarged to enclose the area of 2." means "The rectangle we constructed has area of at most 2. If you are pedantic and insist on meeting the requirement that R has an area of exactly 2, enlarge this rectangle as needed".

Note: In some cases, the question is phrased as "contained within a rectangle with area at most 2". So, semantics is up to you. I

Comment: Oh...i didn't catch that..

Comment: "Line AE separates R into two smaller rectangles, say RG and RC"...this statement need not be correct for all quadrilaterals right?...for example if K has 2 obtuse angles..

Comment: __Hint:__ I believe that you have not yet used the assumed condition that $AE$ is the longest edge. Using this, show that "Every vertex must be below $L_A$ and above $L_E$" (actually more restrictive, but that is sufficient for our purposes). Then, conclude that the polygon is contained in $R_G$ and $R_C$ (whose edge include $L_A, L_E$).

Comment: Let ABCE be our polygon in the same figure..how do we proceed then?